# How to sign and deploy WPF application as a trusted application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

Um using clickonce option to deploy my WPF application 
I have used the signtool to sign the .exe file which  created after doing a clickonce . In the WPF project properties um not checkin the sign option but when I tried to run the application in another PC it says cannot trust.

Then I signed the manifest by using mage as well though the certification file was created by me .

How may I do a signed trsuted deployment of my application ?
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trusted Application Deployment`, part of the `ClickOnce` deployment technology, makes it easier for organizations of any size to grant additional permissions to a managed application in a safer, more secure manner without user prompting. With Trusted Application Deployment, an organization can just configure a client computer to have a list of trusted publishers, who are identified using Authenticode certificates. Thereafter, any `ClickOnce` application signed by one of these trusted publishers receives a higher level of trust.

You must follow these steps to take advantage of Trusted Application Deployment:

1. Obtain a certificate for the publisher.
2. Add the publisher to the trusted publishers store on all clients.
3. Create your ClickOnce application.
4. Sign the deployment manifest with the publisher's certificate.
5. Publish the application deployment to client computers.

Read [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx).

Comment: means do I need to purchase a certificate ?

Comment: All ClickOnce applications must be signed with a digital certificate, regardless of whether they participate in Trusted Application Deployment.

Comment: "Add the publisher to the trusted publishers store on all clients." do we have to do this manually ? @BKO

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the trusted certificates. To see what certificates are trusted for your operating system, go to:
`Window+r` -> `certmgr.msc`